PHP 8.3 chmod(): Operation not permitted
I'm having a problem after upgrading php 8.1 to 8.3 (fpm) in my Ubuntu 22.04
I'm getting "chmod(): Operation not permitted" in CodeIgniter, craftCMS and other web apps.
Those web-apps are hosted in a ntfs partition mounted to /media/www as shown from my /etc/fstab file
UUID=58AA44XXXA3421C /media/www ntfs-3g uid=myuser,gid=mygroup,nls=utf8,umask=002,windows_names 0 0

Therefore, I cannot exec sudo chown -R myuser:www-data (and/or similar commands) in this folder.
PS: My user belongs to www-data etc. This was not happenning on php8.1
Is there any setting I could change in php.ini or similar that can make this work?
I'm trying everything along with this little sample code, but any solution found on Google, Gemini, chatGPT etc. works
<?php
  // the txt file exists
  $file = './example.txt';

  // Change the permissions of the file
  if (chmod($file, 0644)) {
      echo "Permissions changed successfully!";
  } else {
      echo "Failed to change permissions.";
  }

Thanks

It may be that the issue was always there but only the severity changed. If you want to test this hypothesis try using @chmod($file, 0644) to suppress any errors to see if the code behaves like before

NTFS permissions are vastly and fundamentally different from linux FS permissions, which is why the mount specifies what user/group/mask to pretend to be on the linux side. Your chmod() code never worked, and never will. Most likely the error_reporting() value changed and you can actually see the error now.
